# Open source code sharing and dependency management Java for the rest of us

Tags: java, maven, open-source, sharing, dependency-management

I am new to Java and I come from Ruby and I have a question about how can we easily share code we develop so anyone can use them. So far I have been using Maven to resolve dependencies but all of them were developed by large organizations such as the Apache Foundation and in the home page of the project I can not see how to add a library of mine to their repositories.

In Ruby we generally use RubyGems (rubygems.org) to publish open source code. Anyone can do it. Is there an equivalent to Java? How is the submission process? Can anyone participate? Can it be integrated with Maven?

I do not want to merely share JARs. Unless that is the only way.

I think these questions are fundamental for anyone trying to really learn the language and understand its ecosystem.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want to release a library to maven: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Comment: BTW: Not only apache libraries are on Maven, and a lot are from small projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to host an opensource project, look at:

- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/)
- [CodeHaus](http://www.codehaus.org/)
- [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com)
- [JavaForge.com](http://www.javaforge.com)
- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- ... probably others as well

If you want to release a project to Maven, you can use the Sonatype OSS Maven Repository, see their [Usage Guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide).

Comment: CodePlex and BitBucket are also popular project hosting sites

Answer (score 1):

Try [GitHub](https://github.com/), its easy and open source.
PS: Its not specific to Java.